# Import column from another table in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables in mysql server: user AND user_reviews. In the user_reviews I have the reviews that users make and in this user_reviews table I (of course) have a column named "user_id" which relates to the user id in the "user" table. It's a foreign key.

I am using phpmyadmin to read data of the user_reviews table and sometimes I need to correct something (something was mispelled...) and I can just single click a table cell and edit that cell's content easily using phpmyadmin.

BUT in phpmyadmin I can only see the "user_id" number. How can I also be able to see other data from the "user" table? For example, it would be muh easier being able to see the "user_name" in the "user_reviews" table. I know I can use MYSQL commands to match the id in the "user" table with the "user_id" in the "users_reviews" table. But I lose the ability to edit data in the interface of phpmyadmin.

So, is there some mysql command that I can run when I create a table so it creates a column that imports data from another table and displays it?

Comment: update your question with proper formating

Comment: No, you have to tell IT which key to use in a foreign key. Otherwise it would be guess work

Comment: You should create your own admin GUI that can display the names instead of the ids using a simple join, but still store the underlying id value as well to enable updating the database. What you are asking is denormalisation, which may be a useful **optimisation** technique, but should be avoided for the sake of simple admin stuff.

Comment: I think you should try **view** It will list you related data from both user and user_reviews, One more thing can you please share database schema of both the tables(user and user_reviews). ;)

Comment: thanks guys! So it's not possible to display data from another table "importing" it only to the view? For that I would have to craete a view?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 using VIEW can I still edit the results after creating the view? I mean, if I edit some cell will it be saved to the corresponding table?

Comment: You can pull whatever data you want into a view, but it will not be updateable by itself. You would need a data access layer, like ADO.Net that would do this for you, or you need to create such layer for yourself. In phpmyadmin this is not possible, in php in general you can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in phpMyadmin you can do it by joining the 2 tables. something like this "SELECT r.*, u.username FROM `user_reviews` r LEFT JOIN user u on r.user_id = u.id;" but you will get a warning about editing the rows "Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available."

By following the help link from the warning (https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_RowActionLinksWithoutUnique) the phpMyAdmin docs says that you can enable the editing by setting the following  config $cfg['RowActionLinksWithoutUnique']  to true.

The documentation also adds a warning about it 
"Using row actions in the absence of a unique key may result in different/more rows being affected since there is no guaranteed way to select the exact row(s).".

It seems that the same config will allow you to also edit a view.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend! I am trying to accept your answer but it does not mark as acepted. I will try accepting it later if it still does not work ok?